# Designing a Database Table for Unique Email-Document Associations

Tags: sql, entity-framework, relational-database

I have a database containing two main objects: `Area` and  `Document`.

- Each `Area` can have multiple `Documents`.
- Each `Document` belongs to a single `Area`.

In the current version, a `Document` is created by uploading a file. Now, I need to implement the capability to create a Document from an email and ensure that there is only one `Document` associated with that email within an `Area`. To uniquely identify emails, I plan to use the hash of the EML file.

Currently, the relevant object structures are as follows:

- `Area`: id, name
- `Document`: id, areaId, name, ...

To manage the associations between emails and documents, I'm considering introducing a new table, `MailDocument`, to avoid inserting empty values (since documents associated with emails will be a minority).

**Question:** What columns should this table contain to ensure the uniqueness described earlier (i.e., an email should be associated with only one document in the same area)? Is it sufficient to use the EML file hash and the document id, or should I also consider the `areaId`?

Proposed `MailDocument` table structure:

- id
- hash (hash of the EML file)
- documentId
- areaId

Please advise on whether this design adequately enforces the desired uniqueness constraint and whether there are any potential pitfalls or improvements that could be made.

Comment: And what is your RDBMS?

Comment: SQL and I use EntityFramework core

Comment: SQL is the standard language, EF is the mapper, the RDBMS should be SQL SERVER, ORACLE...

Comment: The RDBMS is SQL SERVER, but My doubt is purely at a theoretical level. Given that an email can be linked to only one document, and that document can in turn be associated with a singular area, I am questioning whether the inclusion of areaId in the MailDocument table (and consequently, the relationship between email and area) might be redundant. This is because the document itself already preserves the connection to its respective area. I am attempting to ascertain if there could be further optimization potential in this design.

Comment: I already provided an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing looks good and I think it is  sufficient to enforce the uniqueness constraint. However, to truly ensure that an email is associated with only one document in the same area, you should set a unique constraint on the combination of the `hash` and `areaId` columns.

- `id`: primary key
- `hash` (hash of the EML file): part of a composite unique constraint with `areaId`
- `documentId`: foreign key referencing the `Document` table, with a unique constraint (as each email should correspond to exactly one document)
- `areaId`: part of a composite unique constraint with `hash`

Here is how you can define your table:

```
CREATE TABLE MailDocument (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  hash VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  documentId INT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  areaId INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (documentId) REFERENCES Document(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (areaId) REFERENCES Area(id),
  UNIQUE (hash, areaId)
);
```